# Plot a histogram of all volumes in nifti dataset

Tags: dataset, histogram, volume, nifti

I have loaded a nifti dataset using nibabel tool, but I dont have idea how to plot a histogram with all volumes in the dataset.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62185989/edit) the post to include your own effort into solving this problem. The latter preferably in code, this is called a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: maybe you can use [histogramdd](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogramdd.html) from Numpy, or maybe you can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51624315/)